# ASP.NET MVC 3 validation order

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

As part of our ASP.NET MVC3 project, we have implemented some custom validation. On a particular entity e.g. UniqueMandatoryCode, we have got [Required] and our [CustomValidationDataAnnotation].

They both work but I would like to know what is happening under the hood in terms of the order of execution for validation. The issue I have is that our CustomValidation code is hit before the [Required] validation. This poses problems when we pass empty values.

So the question is, how do I control the order of validation i.e. first go through the [Required] validation and then the [CustomValidationDataAnnotation] validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the validation order cannot be easily controlled. 
The common technique is to ignore the empty/unspecified case in all other validators (ignore = you treat it as valid). You will anyway add a required validator if the value is mandatory that will handle that case. If the value is optional, why would you apply the custom validation rule on an empty/unspecified value?

Comment: This is effectively what I'm doing in my custom code. I'm ignoring it and treating as valid and leaving it to the built-in validation to handle. However, to do that I have extra code to check for null values and I wanted to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I still don't understand how the ordering of rules would help you to add your validator to an optional field if you don't check for null. I think it is still better to separate these concerns, even if you know that in your case the fields will be always mandatory. An infrastructure and configuration for the order of validation rules would be probably too complicated to implement and use compared to the benefit that you can spare an initial if in your validators.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make things clearer tbh. I was hoping that if the system would first hit the [required] validation, it wouldn't proceed to my custom validation which contain the checking for null values, hence saving me some lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I understand this scenario. This would require the validation framework to prioritize the required validation and to stop further validations on that field if it failed. I'm quite sure that this is not supported out of the box. Even if it was supported, I would recommend to go for the robust implementation and check for empty/null value instead of relying on such hidden dependencies. Since this is not common practice, nobody would expect that your custom validator can be used in combination with a required validator only, so it would cause problems if someone reuses your validator later.

Comment: Ah this is the answer I was after. Since it's not behaviour supported out of the box, then I will carry on checking for null values. Thx.